# Angular 2 canDeactivate isn't always routing

Tags: angular, routes, promise

I've a component with a Cancel button.  When this is hit the gotoParent() gets called:

```
canDeactivate(): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  return this.dialogService.confirm('Discard changes?');
}

private gotoParent() {
  let orgId = this.org ? this.org.id : -1;
  this.router.navigate(['../', { id: orgId }], { relativeTo: this.route });
  console.info("orgId: " + orgId);
}

cancel() {
  this.gotoParent();
}
```

Because I've a deactivation guard implemented for the route I (usually) see a dialog:

```
@Injectable()
export class DialogService {
  confirm(message?: string) {
    return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
      return resolve(window.confirm(message || 'Is it OK?'));
    });
  };
}
```

My problem is that this works once.  If I click component Cancel a second time I get no response -- no dialog.  Neither does the component Save button work.

When I trace my code I see the router.navigate() being executed -- the console.info() is there so I can set a breakpoint -- but the dialog doesn't appear and the application doesn't navigate.

At this point I can click on some "master" button to go to the root of the application.  Then I get that dialog again.  If I click on the dialog Cancel for this instance of the dialog then that stops working as well.

What should occur is the dialog Cancel should leave me in the current component display, ready to show the dialog again.

This worked in the original tutorial, but not after I've changed things for my own purposes.  Does someone have a clue for me?

Thanks,
Jerome.

**EDIT:** Replying to YairTawil requires more space than a comment could provide.

Here are my events after I inserted the listener for events.

Navigate from the global menu into edit-org:

```
event =  NavigationEnd {id: 4, url: "/provider/edit-org", urlAfterRedirects: "/provider/edit-org"}
```

Click on component Cancel:

```
event =  NavigationStart {id: 5, url: "/provider;id=12"}
org-detail.component.ts:67 event =  RoutesRecognized {id: 5, url: "/provider;id=12", urlAfterRedirects: "/provider;id=12", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
```

(The id=12 is a tutorial trick to tell the parent which ID was worked on.)

Click on dialog Cancel:

```
org-detail.component.ts:67 event =  NavigationCancel {id: 5, url: "/provider;id=12", reason: ""}
```

Back to the component.

Click again on component Cancel.  No event.  Click on component Save.  No event.

Clicking on a global menu choice "Provider" yields these events:

```
event =  RoutesRecognized {id: 6, url: "/provider", urlAfterRedirects: "/provider", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
org-detail.component.ts:67 event =  NavigationCancel {id: 6, url: "/provider", reason: ""}
```

After clicking on dialog Cancel the global menu Provider no longer works.  It is as though something wants to be cleared or reset.

I **can** reliably get the event to fire every time by clicking alternately on the component Cancel, dialog Cancel, then the global menu Provider button, then the dialog Cancel, then repeat.  But consecutive clicks on the collection of component buttons, such as (component Cancel, dialog Cancel, then component Cancel) doesn't yield that second dialog appearance.

Any more ideas?

Jerome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of debugging, comparing progressively stripped versions of my program and the Angular 2 "Routing" tutorial (from Plunker).  After a while I realized that the code between the two was identical, but I was getting different results.  The answer isn't going to be in the app directory.

I got to index.html (my Gulp file copies index-jit.html into there) and found that some included Javascript is influencing my result.  I'm not understanding why this is the "fix", but changing some Javascript include files is working for me.

My index.html included these files and called an import:

```
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>
  System.import('system-config.js')
  .then(function() { System.import('main'); })
  .catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

The Angular 2 tutorial from Plunker has these lines instead:

```
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.8"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js"></script>

<script>
  System.import('app')
        .catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

When I make the substitutions my program is now working as expected. Every click of the component Cancel button gives me a Dialog, and the dialog Cancel returns me to the component.

Thanks all for listening in.

Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

There is faw types of events that angular2 router send when it start navigate:

- navigationStart
- navigationError,
- navigationCancel,
- navigationEnd....

when CanDeactivate get 'false' navigationCancel event should send.

You can follow router events:

```
  import {Router} from "@angular/router";
  export class MyClass{
  constructor( private router:Router ) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      console.log("event = ",event) 
      ... search what happend with your navigation
    }
  }
```

}